# Limit Comparison Test Defined entirely in symbolic notation

Tags: calculus, notation

Is it possible to define the limit comparison test entirely with symbols (no textual explanation), or with as little textual explanation as possible? How?

My latest best attempt:

$0<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}<\infty\implies \sum{a_n}=\infty(XOR)\sum{b_n}=\infty$

Comment: First you need to define converge and diverge, preferably in such a way that one and only one of them is true for every sequence.

Comment: I would start with $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=c>0 \Rightarrow $..., then reference the convergence/divergence of $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$.

Comment: Modified the question to reflect these considerations. Still doesn't feel complete.

Comment: yeah, xor is one or the other but not both. We want to keep the idea, ($\sum a_n \wedge \sum b_n$ converge)$\vee$($\sum a_n \wedge \sum b_n$ diverge). Also XOR is not a common mathematical notation, but I like your style (reaching for logic gates). Actually your edit says this. I have just never seen xor in math notation.

Comment: Yes I wasn't sure if their was a XOR, but seeing that their isn't I guess I must go the long way. Provide your suggestions as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: OOh that's nice! Just replace the $\infty$ with $\pm \infty$ (possible right?) and then substitute the $\mathbb{R}$ with say $c$ and $d$, noting $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ in the tail. Man I think you have it with that! It was sort of what I was thinking earlier, but seeing you write it, it does not seem so lengthy.

Comment: Added the plus minus fix. Why c and d?

Comment: Woah, no strike that! $\sum a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ meaning the sum converges to an element of the reals, this is fine. My bad. That is actually pretty cool, I did not think about that. This explains why it looks so much tighter that I originally envisioned.

Comment: I'd like to be able to mark an answer to this question so other forum users will know its been answered; can you post one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your assistance, and this was alot of fun,

$$\left(0<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}<\infty\right)\Rightarrow \left(\sum{a_n}=\pm\infty\wedge\sum{b_n}=\pm\infty \right)\vee \left(\sum{a_n}\in\mathbb{R}\wedge\sum{b_n}\in\mathbb{R} \right).$$